# Select X random users per item

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, random

I have 2 tables: `Items` & `Users`.

`Items` contains `ItemID, and Num_Users`
`Users` contains `UserID`

For each `ItemID`, I need to randomly select a number of Users according to the value stated in the Num_Users column.

I created a sample set of data on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bdde1).

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?  What have you searched for?

Comment: Just to be clear--I answered but think I might have misunderstood the question--are you looking to have a *random value based on Num_Users* returned, or *a random **number of users** based on Num_Users* returned?

Comment: Neither. I'm looking for a random set of users the size of which is determined by the Num_Users returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bdde1/5)

```
SELECT Items.[ItemID],
       UserID
FROM   Items
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP ([Num_Users]) *
                    FROM   Users
                    ORDER  BY Newid()) A
```

You could also use `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)` instead of `Newid()` for a greater degree of randomness but there are [some issues with this](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/654809/crypt-gen-random-erroneously-treated-as-constant) on non up-to-date versions of SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Why isn't NewID random enough? Does it have a non-random aspect to it?

Comment: @Gidil - [GUIDs are designed to be unique, not random](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/23/10309199.aspx) so using something specifically there for randomness might be preferable. Depends upon your needs. `NEWID` seemed to have better performance than `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` last time I tested this though.